# how to get the name of the target on click and assign the value to another variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, variables

So I have an empty variable

```
var pName= null;
```

Everytime I click on an image I want the variable 'pName' to change to the name of that image

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').on('click', check)
});

function check(){
    pName == target.name.value;
    console.log('pName');
}
```

now I want to put the value of this variable into a hidden form (or any other way, if you suggest it), pick it up in php and change the value of the variable "$pName" (in php) to the value of the  hidden form.

```
<label><input type="hidden" name="pNameChange" value=""></label>
```

and I want to do this on every page. My code doesn't seem to work.

*Edit*

I have a variable that I use on every page $pName (php). I want it to dynamically change to the name of the image you click. I don't know if I'm doing it the right way.

*Edit2*

This is my projects php file:

```
<?php
$newRecord = null;
$pName = "kkk";
$db_connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',"project_online_planner");
if (!$db_connection){
    die('Failed to connect to MySql:'.mysql_error());
}

//insert into database
if(isset($_POST['insertComments'])){
    include('connect-mysql.php');
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO user_comments (username, comment, project) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '$pName')";
        if (!mysqli_query($db_connection, $sqlinsert)){
            die('error inserting new record');
        }
        else{
            $newRecord = "1 record added";
        }//end nested statement

}

//text from database
$query="SELECT * FROM user_comments where project = '$pName' ";
$results = mysqli_query($db_connection,$query);
$intro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

$query2="SELECT * FROM project where name = '$pName' ";
$results2 = mysqli_query($db_connection,$query2);
$intro2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results2);


?>
```

Here I use $pName as the name of the project. every image in my project has the name of the project they are in. I'm trying to dynamically change value of the variable $pName into what image is clicked.

this is my all projects php file:

```
<?php
$pName =
$db_connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',"project_online_planner");
if (!$db_connection){
    die('Failed to connect to MySql:'.mysql_error());
}
$query="SELECT * FROM project ";
$results = mysqli_query($db_connection,$query);
$intro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project planner online</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ppo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ppo.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bgNav">
    <nav id="nav">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a class="rightNav" href="register.php">Register</a>
        <a class="rightNav" href="login.php">Log in</a>
    </nav>
</div>
<h2 class="titlePage">All projects</h2>
<div id="hugeTile">
    <?php

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $project = $row["project"];
        echo "<div class='allProjectsWrapper'>";
        echo nl2br("<div class='allProjectsTitle'>" . $row['name'] . "</div>");
        echo nl2br("<div class='project'>" ."<img name=\"$project\" width='240px' height='170px'  src='". $row['image'] ."'/>". "</div>");
        echo "</div>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
<form>
    <label><input type="hidden" name="pNameChange" value=""></label>
</form>
```

Comment: you want to get the name of current image?

Comment: Yes, I have a variable that I use on every page. I want it to dynamically change to the name of the image you click. I don't  know if I'm doing it the right way.

Comment: Do you get `$pName` from a database in php?

Comment: what is the name of the image? Are u declaring name via some data- attribite, or via id/class, or via href, or via alt?

Comment: No, I want to have a variable $pName and have the value equal to the value of the form. I don't know how to do this in php without submitting it. all the content of the page changes depending on the value of $pName. this is an example of one of my queries:

    $query="SELECT * FROM user_comments where project = '$pName' ";

$pName should be the name of the project in the database. My code work it's just that I want it to change dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

use like this,

```
$('img').click(function(){
   pname= $(this).attr("name");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First add an ID to the hidden field

```
<label><input type="hidden" name="pNameChange" id="pNameChange" value=""></label>
```

Then you can pick up the image name like this

```
$('img').click(function()
{
    path = $(this).attr('src').split('\/');
    $img_name = path[path.length-1];
    $('#pNameChange').val($img_name); //Changing the pNameChange value
});
```

If you simply want to change the value of "`pNameChange`" after clicking the image, you don't need PHP.

Also, when you do

```
pName == target.name.value;
```

It doesn' assign value, it uses comparison.

`=` is used to assign values.

`==` is used for comparison

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your var globally defined, get the `href` attribute from the image and then set the input by its name, since you have no ID there:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pName = '';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img').on('click', function(){
            pName = $(this).attr('href');
            $("input[name=pNameChange]").val(pName);
        })
    }); 
</script>
```

`this` in the local scope will be the image element from the DOM.

You'll need to parse the href attr that you are sending in php because it will have the whole img url, unless you use a custom attribute or put the name in the image id or something like that:

```
<?php 
    $segments = explode('/', $pName);

    if(!empty($segments)) {
        $length = count($segments);
        $img_name = $segments[$length-1];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Over here we have to assume that image name is same as image href.

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash He does not give any hint of what name means to him... besides if he needs to do something on backend, most probably he wants to actually get the filename of that image, I'm assuming of course.

Comment: Sorry for being so vague, I just edited it with more details.

Answer (score -1):

Just use this in your check() function:

```
$("#pNameChange").val(pname);
```

and dont forget to add id "pNameChange" to your input

```
<input type="hidden" id="pNameChange" name="pNameChange" value="">
```